# Change login screen to gnome-shell login

Tags: gnome

I was just goofing around in a vm to test what would happen if I purgen unity:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge unity*
```

I found that I get an startup error, but when I proceed, I got this awesome login screen:
[image: all sexy]
It has an sexy effect and is just the gnome style my whole pc has got.

So can any one please tell me how I change the default login screen program without having to bother clicking "fix this error" on every boot?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]:

I have been able to change it(my own answer), but now I see the old purple background for a second when I logged in, and that background is only used in the old greeter screen.
How do I change it(or where are those backgrounds located)?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: uhhh, lemme crash my vm again, 2 sec.
But it is in no way a addition to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

I selected gdm, and now I have the login screen I desire.(This replaces lightdm with gdm)

Thanks for the other suggestions, I found that this was the only one to work, since gnome has it's own desktop manager(gdm).

Answer (score 0):

Boot in recovery mode, select root shell and issue: `dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg`. The error is related to misconfigured xorg. Have you installed the virtualbox extension pack? If not, do it!

Comment: thanks, but I dont mind the error, but the login screen it revealed, how do I install that? thats my question.

Comment: Get rid of error, and you will have the login screen.

Comment: well surely there would be a nicer way to change the logon screen, I mean, we can edit anything here, why should I have to break 50% of my system to change a silly logon screen?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lightdm as display manager, you can change the greeter in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

For example to use lightdm-gtk-greeter (=xfce greater):

```
#greeter-session=unity-greeter
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter

# Other options:

# to change unity to xfce session on default:
#user-session=ubuntu
user-session=xfce
# or to xubuntu:
#user-session=xubuntu

# hide users
greeter-hide-users=true

# disable guest login
allow-guest=false
```

As you can see there are more customization options to hide users or to select the default session for example.
I don't know the name of the login screen on your picture so I used the one I use on my machine but I guess you can find it out on your virtual machine and use it on your main if that is what you want to do.